# Lambda function times out after finishing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that is completing without errors (I get to the `console.log()` line), but still times out. I have tried debugging with `lambda-local`, but cannot find where the hold up is. I read multiple places that I should include `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` in my handler function, but that makes no difference error. Is there something else I'm missing or not calling that is preventing this function from not timing out? After the `consol.log()` function gets printed, END RequestID, and REPORT RequestID, this error gets printed `2018-11-05T23:42:24.357Z 705cea03-e154-11e8-8089-87f7086f1090 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds`

Here is my handler's function:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
    let alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    // To enable string internationalization (i18n) features, set a 
resources object.
    alexa.resources = languageStrings;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
    console.log("You made it.")
};
```

Comment: I was under the impression that was how lambdas were supposed to behave. Perhaps you are looking for a different AWS solution?

Comment: When you say "it times out" what are you referring to? What symptoms are you describing that tell you it's timed out?

Comment: @jarmod  I updated the problem to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a callback.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
    let alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    // To enable string internationalization (i18n) features, set a 
resources object.
    alexa.resources = languageStrings;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
    console.log("You made it.")
    callback(null,"Complete");
};
```

Since you have disabled `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`. It is going to wait until you initiate the `callback` function call.

Hope it helps.